# Oracle SQL: write manually a text

Tags: sql, oracle, select, text, manual

I am currently trying to just get a certain format of a bill, but I don't know how to select a custom test.

For Example, I Select something like this

```
Name   Age   Birthday     Gender

Jonas  26    01.01.2000   Boy
```

The Boy in this one is no Information that is in a table but manually made and I don't know how to do that. Every other Information is from a Table (that was easy).

Summary: How do I manually write a text into a Select?

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, age, birthday, 'Boy' as gender
from your_table             ---------------               
                            like this!
```